# I can't open the ports, any suggestions?

Tags: port

I can't open the ports, im trying to open several ports at once, but it doesn't work, I tried to open them separately (1x1) and it doesn't work either.

Comment: Is this a programming question? If so, where is your code?

Comment: it is a question about the VPC section of GCP, more specifically in the firewall section